# show posts with range meta key

Tags: wp-query

i want to show posts with age between 5 and 10 usind WP_Query.how i can do this?

```
$args = array(
'post_type'  => 'my_custom_post_type',
'meta_key'   => 'age',
'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
'order'      => 'ASC',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'age',
        'value'   => array( 3, 4 ),
        'compare' => 'IN',
    ),
),);$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare BETWEEN in the `meta_query` and you need to set the type too for NUMERIC.

For example

```
$args = array(
'post_type'  => 'my_custom_post_type',
'meta_key'   => 'age',
'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
'order'      => 'ASC',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'age',
        'value'   => array( 5, 10 ),
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
    )
));
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```